# Add page break in css and pdf

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp, dompdf

I was trying to make a report in pdf with the Dompdf library. I added a header and a footer with this code

```css
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #333399;
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 116px;
    background: url('http://ibadep.local/img/header2.png') no-repeat;
}
```

and they appeared correctly on all pages.

Inside the page, I have a table that displays a lot of information (a php `foreach`), and when the table becomes very large, the trs appear behind the footer of the 1st page, and the header of 2nd page. I don't want this, I want that when the tr reaches near the footer, the page is breaked, and the next row show bellow the header, not behind like what's happening now.

I've tried a lot of things with the `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` properties, but none of that worked. What can I do???

Comment: So tell us what you have tried? Then we can make alternate suggestions

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but may I suggest that you use `id` (#) instead of a `class` when using footers and headers. Classes are usually used when you wish to apply a particular style to many elements at a time. If you have other elements bearing the same class as you wrote, you will end up with problems. *Just saying*

Comment: When working with CSS, using classes for table elements is not suggested, you are best to use ID's instead of classes. That is probably why it's not working for you. I suggest you [**Google**](https://www.google.ca/search?q=apply+CSS+style+to+HTML+table+tr+td&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr) "apply CSS style to HTML table tr td" just for the sake of it. It may very well help. Cheers

Comment: @Fred I would even more recommend using `<header></header>` and `<footer></footer>`.

Comment: @JeffNoel `<footer></footer>` sure, `<header></header>` no. Those (header) are reserved HTML tags for meta, title, etc. and including link rel to CSS ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the page margin.  This will prevent the page content from rendering in the space allocated for the header and footer..

```
@page { 
    margin: 120px 50px 35px 50px; 
}
```

You will also need to set the `top` on your `header` to a negative value to push the element outside of the margin. The same applies to the footer.

`top: -90px`

You can test it by pasting the code below into the [DOMPDF Demo](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/docs_0-6-0/demo.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@page {
    margin: 120px 50px 80px 50px; 
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -50px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #333399;
}
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: -100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 116px;
    background: url('http://ibadep.local/img/header2.png') no-repeat;
}
/* Type some style rules here */

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    This is the header
</div>
<div id="footer">
    This is the footer
</div>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td><td>Column2</td><td>Column3</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- Type some HTML here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You took out the "**#**" in `footer {` in your edit, any special reason?

Comment: Taking your advice, I replaced the <div> with <footer>

Comment: The <footer> tag is supported in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari. Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the <footer> tag. So it might not be a good idea to use the `<footer>` tag and best left as an `ID`. That way it can easily be manipulated. You would be surprised in knowing that there still are people using IE8 and earlier.

Comment: This is DOMPDF, it accepts footer tag - switching back to <div> because that's what he's using in his example

Comment: Do IE8 and earlier versions support DOMPDF? Not the `<footer>` tag, from what I know.

Comment: Sure, if you have acrobat installed

Comment: Well, no word from the OP. I guess this is a "sit and wait" situation.

Comment: This solved my problem! I didn't know that I can set a negative value to elements. I don't have much knowledge of css ;) Thank you!