# Top margin on second page does not work - Laravel DOMPDF

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf

When you try to apply top margin on the second page the header does not behave correctly.

Page 1:
[image]

Page 2:
[image]

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

@page {
    margin: 100px 25px;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: -70px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}

main {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100px;
    left: -60px;
    right: -60px;
    background-color: #3f8d99;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    color: white;
}

footer .pagenum:before {
    content: counter(page);
}

footer .pagenum-container {
    margin-top: 16px;
    float: right;
}
```

I tried to follow some ideas, especially from this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153069/dompdf-top-margin-after-page-break-not-working), but I did not succeed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Go to second page and `inpect ` in chrome  and see `main {
    margin-top: 60px;
}` this is visible or not ?

Comment: It does not make much sense to do it because I'm in an environment where the browser is generating a PDF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I changed some lines of the CSS file.

```
@page {
    margin: 140px 25px 100px 25px;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: -136px;
    left: -60px;
    right: -60px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And removed main class.

```
/*main {
    margin-top: 30px;
}*/
```

See the result. Page 2:

[image]

Comment: That's the way to do it. You define page margins then push the header/footer into those margins using negative positioning.